# instantiate and add a movieclip.

Tags: actionscript-3

Tried finding some info on this without success.
When instantiating a movieclip for later use. Is it using a lot of performance before actually adding it to stage? The question is when is flash working more. At adding to stage or instantiating to mmemory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is in it and what it is doing. If everything in it is graphic, it should only use CPU if it is on the Display list.  If it has ActionScript code, it will depend on what that code is doing. For example, listening for ENTER_FRAME will use significant CPU cycles, as will instantiating new objects. Note that having objects coming and going from the timeline also instantiates objects.

If the object contains a lot of data (for example a BitmapData that is a 1000 x 1000 uncompressed jpg), then it will use a lot of memory.